# Not able to Create Database or Restore Database on the Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to restore database on the Azure SQL Managed Instance using Azure blob container URL.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-get-started-restore)

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://zzdevbackup.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackup] 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'
, SECRET = 'sv=2017-11-09&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacg=XzzcvDrhcmdldnfQ9Opu4M4Kqq1MT3tsxOADiRCQBf%2BXo%3D'

RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM URL = 
   'https://zzdevbackup.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackup/Azure_Data_Sync_Test.bak'

RESTORE DATABASE [Azure_Data_Sync_Test] FROM URL = 'https://zzdevbackup.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackup/Azure_Data_Sync_Test.bak'
```

I am getting the below error

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
>   Cannot open backup device ‘https://ZZZdevbackup.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackup/Azure_Data_Test.bak’. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Please help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: Does the RESTORE FILELISTONLY work?    When the secret was created did you give it a long enough time to live?  I think the default is one day, you need to increase that before you generate the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you created the storage account as shown below:

[image]

You need to use Classic and Standard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It fixed after re-creating the container with the new access level

[image]